# Scheduled task does not run Hyper-V VM unless I connect to GUI

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, hyper-v, powershell-remoting, hypervisor

I have a script which launches an app on the VM and logs some data for the app. As powershell script does not allow me to run the app in foreground I decided to schedule a task after 2 mins and then keep polling for the task completion. This worked flawlessly when I am connected to the Hyper-V VM. But as soon as I run this script via my automation (no gui) it does not run this scheduled task.

All other ps1 scripts do their job just fine - installing the product and copying some files.

Below are the powershell commands I run on the VM:

```
    $password= "password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force; 
    $username = "name";
    $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password);
    Invoke-Command -VMName INSTANCE_ID -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock 
        {
          $gettime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(2);
          $run = $gettime.ToString('HH:mm');
          $action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'C:\logging.bat';
          $trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At $run;
          $principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -GroupID "BUILTIN\Administrators" -RunLevel Highest;
          Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Principal $principal -TaskName "ID_Logging_Task" -Description "my description"
        }
```

Then I wait for 4 mins in my code. Before I start polling for my job status.

```
$password= "password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force; 
$username = "name";
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password);
Invoke-Command -VMName INSTANCE_ID -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock 
    {
            $timer =  [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew();
            $timeout = 2000;
            while (((Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'ID_Logging_Task').State -eq  'Running') -and  ($timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds -lt $timeout)) 
        {
                Write-Verbose  -Message 'Waiting on scheduled task...';
                Start-Sleep -Seconds  3;
        } 
            $timer.Stop();
     }
```

By adding logs I have confirmed that the poller barely polls for 2 seconds. And it is also not the case that my batch file has finished working in 4 minutes as it has produced no outputs(it should create a basic output every time it runs). The scheduled task never goes from "Ready" state to "Running" state when I am not connected to the GUI of the VM.

What can be the issue here and how can I fix this?

### **UPDATE**

The issue indeed is that the Principal I have set runs my task in Admin mode only when the user is logged in. To solve this I tried to provide various combinations of LogonType values but to no avail.

[Schedule task creation with option ""Run whether user is logged in or not"" using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48085919/schedule-task-creation-with-option-run-whether-user-is-logged-in-or-not-usin)

The above answer says it is possible to run without logging in if we pass password in script. I am fine with doing this. Can anyone help me with the script which allows both Admin mode and no logging in. I also looked at [Task Scheduler is not supporting option "Run with highest Privilege" and "Run weather user is logged on or not"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44426636/task-scheduler-is-not-supporting-option-run-with-highest-privilege-and-run-we) but this also does not provide any solutions. Also I do not need to access the Network in any way.

Added more information on - [Difference between BUILTIN\Administrators and normal Administrators Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71724814/difference-between-builtin-administrators-and-normal-administrators-group)

Comment: You should check the settings in the task. When you edit it, you might see that you have enabled to only run when user is logged in. So, you might select the second option which is independent from your login state.

Comment: @An-dir You are correct. It is a problem with logging. I am trying to use the LogonType parameter but after using it I am not able to run my script in Admin mode. Can you please help with script which allows running without logging in and with Administrator privileges. I am fine with passing password in my script.